# Backing up i.imgur.com images that may be at risk due to their new ToS

Tags: discussion, image

Now, you should be using the "add picture" feature in the editor to get an i.stack.imgur.com address for your images in your posts. That is hosting that SE pays for and images there won't get deleted. However, we have some posts that use free hosting, namely i.imgur.com. On May 15th, Imgur is [changing their ToS](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029-Imgur-Terms-of-Service-Update-April-19-2023-) and will be "removing old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account" which may include some of our images on free hosting. (See [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/323179) for more details.)

I came up with a plan to back up every single one of these images without bumping too many posts in a short time: we upload all these links on meta. I explain a bit more about this in my [answer on SFF Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13901/82909).

Using a series of queries ([returning one image](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/revision/1743757/2119851/top-posts-with-non-stack-imgur-images-order-by-of-views), [returning two images](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1743757/top-posts-with-non-stack-imgur-images-order-by-of-views)), I made this quick and slightly dirty table, which we can use if any of the images break.

Did I miss anything? Does anyone have any questions? (I don't have a question.)

(Based on my [post with the same title on ELU meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15595/191178).)

---

| Post Link | url | count | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A noun describing an activity that one is really good at | /i.imgur.com/skqVtIr.png | 1 | [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z6KJ.png) |
| "regardless whether" vs. "regardless of whether" | /i.imgur.com/jWZ8XAn.png | 1 | [8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9cFB.png) |
| What distinguishes a predicative complement from a direct object? | /i.imgur.com/bDeZ7K3_d.j | 1 | fixed at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/452083/191178) |
| What part is called the crust? | /i.imgur.com/38nkptU.gif | 1 | already deleted; edited post to remove |
| What is this food called in English? | /i.imgur.com/ZzuBysm.jpg | 1 | [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEff8.jpg) |
| Can "Why don't you be" be correct? If so, how is it different from "Why aren't you"? | /i.imgur.com/cEHqzCc.jpg | 1 | [11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5clqD.jpg) |
| A self-deprecating word for really white skin? | /i.imgur.com/fPUUf.jpg" | 1 | [12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGJW7.jpg) |
| What are "brushes" in this context? | /i.imgur.com/98t28QS.jpg | 1 | [13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb7Vb.jpg) |
| Does "less expensive" + "saving money" = "win-win?" | /i.imgur.com/taQDw9g.png | 1 | [14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m4QU.png) |
| passing vs having passed | /i.imgur.com/bBljG9k.png | 1 | [15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCfqe.png) |
| What does “We mortals are but shadows and dust” mean? | /i.imgur.com/0gWF3eg.png | 1 | [16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIGG4.png) |
| Adverb position | /i.imgur.com/fUwTGMB.png | 1 | [17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK3as.png) |
| Does "involved in" means the same as "known as/for"? | /i.imgur.com/QjjILna.jpg | 1 | [18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw17g.jpg) |
| Are "thus" and "such that" really that old-fashioned? | /i.imgur.com/gq6Ibh8.png | 1 | [19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fZa7.png) |
| 'Fall is here' and ' has gone full pumpkin' | /i.imgur.com/An2AyrDm.jp | 1 | [20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV3YA.jpg) |
| What are the most common nouns used with "bits of"? | /i.imgur.com/4D6Jm0Z.jpg | 1 | [21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAknv.jpg) |
| What does "of" + noun do in the beginning of the sentence as subject? | /i.imgur.com/IXR5A1c.png | 1 | [22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmx5O.png) |
| "not good" vs "not very good" - which is more negative? | /i.imgur.com/n74A5Cl.jpg | 1 | [23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSbaL.jpg) |
| Is "Crude" a valid antonym of "Urbane"? | /i.imgur.com/esvH5fh.png | 1 | [24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOXVU.png) |
| Word for mood or (facial) expression if awaiting laughs on a commentary / rhetoric question? | /i.imgur.com/VhgeZvB.png | 1 | [25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jooi7.png) |
| Does a noun always require the definite article when the adjective "occasional" is used before it? | /i.imgur.com/7jrL9wh.jpg | 1 | [26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOnZn.jpg) |
| How do I say that I'm in the process of movement and am going to do something? | /i.imgur.com/LHFVgMs.png | 1 | [27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeAhw.png) |
| How does one use a rostrum? | /i.imgur.com/DtR2tfu.jpg | 2 | [28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZJyT.jpg) |
| What's the name of this walking style used by Luna Lovegood? | /i.imgur.com/TPMbQRh.gif | 2 | gif won't copy; [YouTube link](https://youtu.be/FHE3pxEtVn0?t=68) |
| Wage vs. salary | /i.imgur.com/4bp1Uck.jpg | 2 | fixed manually |
| "Could you please help me" vs "Could you help me please" | /i.imgur.com/owWwclU.png | 2 | fixed manually |

Answer (score -1):

Is this the sort of thing that Stack Exchange really ought to do themselves with the Community bot?